# ¿How i can disable CSRF only for my api with spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite, spring-security, spring-boot

Im creating a project with spring using spring security but i am having problem only with my api(all controllers are working correctly with csrf). But seems like the csrf is causing problem to my api, because when i make a request to my api i get:

```
[{"id":1,"titulo":"vineta3","creationdate":1489329545000,"URL":"http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/125/918/RMUBQ.png","likes":0,"dislikes":0,"descripcion":"des3"},{"id":2,"titulo":"vineta4","creationdate":1489329545000,"URL":"http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/125/163/ragek.jpg?1318992465","likes":0,"dislikes":0,"descripcion":"des4"}]{"timestamp":1489329557093,"status":200,"error":"OK","exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":"No message available","path":"/api/vinetas2/"}
```

The last info:

```
"timestamp":1489329557093,"status":200,"error":"OK","exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":"No message available","path":"/api/vinetas2/"
```

is not returning when my project has not spring secutiry. Im using the next code for my security configuration.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public UserRepositoryAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // Public pages
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/loginerror").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/registro").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll();        


    // Private pages (all other pages)
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").hasAnyRole("USER");
    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/crearComentario/vineta/{id}").hasAnyRole("USER");

    // Login form
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login");
    http.formLogin().usernameParameter("username");
    http.formLogin().passwordParameter("password");
    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/home");
    http.formLogin().failureUrl("/loginerror");

    // Logout
    http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    // Database authentication provider
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

}

and the next for my csrf:

```
@Configuration
public class CSRFHandlerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CSRFHandlerInterceptor());
    }
}

class CSRFHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler,
            final ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf"); 
        modelAndView.addObject("token", token.getToken());      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, randall! This site is purely in Spanish, consider translating your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English https://stackoverflow.com/